# Count of Positives/ Sum of Negatives

Tags: javascript

We are supposed to return the count of all the positive numbers given an array, and the addition of all the numbers given the same array.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong please. I would really appreciate it. This is what I put as my code(JavaScript):

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let arr = [];

  let count = 0;

  let neg = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] > 0) {
      count++;
    } else if (input[i] < 0) {
      neg += input[i];
    }
    return arr.push(count, neg);
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the call off the function, the wanted result and the error, you get. btw, array's indices goes until smaler then the length of it.

Comment: Note that you don't want to `return` _during_ your for loop. You want to return _after_ your for loop. Also note that you want to return that `arr`, not the result of `arr.push` =) (although returning `{ count, neg }` would make more sense than returning an array)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let count = 0;
  let neg = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] > 0) {
      count++;
    } else if (input[i] < 0) {
      neg += input[i];
    }
  }
  // Return outside the for loop
  return [count, neg];
}

console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([1,2,4,-1,0,-2,3,-4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let count = 0;
  let neg = 0;

  for (const number of input) {
    if (number > 0) {
      count++;
    } else if (number < 0) {
      neg += number;
    }
  }
  
  return [count, neg];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
public static int[] countPositivesSumNegatives(int[] input) {
        int countOfPositive = 0;
        int sumOfNegative = 0;

        if (input ==  null || input.length == 0) {
            return new int[] {};
        }

        for (int i: input) {
            if(i > 0) countOfPositive++;
            if (i < 0) sumOfNegative += i;
        }

        return new int[] {countOfPositive, sumOfNegative};
    }
```